# Crop image out of two points (C#)

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, crop

## Update:

Updated code added.

However for some reason it still doesn't work properly. If the coordinates are Bitmap coordinates, what could be the reason? The first code sample I put here doesn't work properly and the second gives me an OutOfMemoryException.

I've ran into a problem trying to crop an image between two points. In my project I have a pictureBox (named AP), and the general idea is that the user clicks on two points and the program crops the image between these two corners. I've tried two methods, one with Bitmap.Crop and the other one with Graphics.DrawImage, but both seemed to fail for the same reason and didn't work at all (cropped a much smaller portion of the image).

Code:

```
    private void AP_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Setting the corners
        else if (mark_shape == 0)
        {
            var mouseEventArgs = e as MouseEventArgs;
            if (picture_corners_set == 0)
            {
                northEast = AP.PointToClient(new Point(mouseEventArgs.X, mouseEventArgs.Y));
                picture_corners_set = 1;
            }
            else if (picture_corners_set == 1)
            {
                southWest = AP.PointToClient(new Point(mouseEventArgs.X, mouseEventArgs.Y));
                Rectangle imageRectangle = new Rectangle(southWest.X, northEast.Y, (northEast.X - southWest.X), (southWest.Y - northEast.Y));
                var bmp = new Bitmap(imageRectangle.Width, imageRectangle.Height);
                using (var gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
                {
                    gr.DrawImage(AP.Image, 0, 0, imageRectangle, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                }
                AP.Image = bmp;
                enableAllButtons();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are the point coordinates relative to the screen, form, or picturebox?

Comment: To the screen, I think; I initialize them as
northEast = new Point(mouseEventArgs.X, mouseEventArgs.Y);

Comment: Since the bitmap crop coordinates are relative to the bitmap, do you translate the mouse coordinates from screen coordinates to client (picturebox) ones anywhere?

Comment: I feared that this is the problem and tried to do this in various ways (Screen class etc.)... do you have any solution for this?

Comment: `Picturebox.PointToClient` transforms screen coordinates to client (control) coordinates, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoclient(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: So if I understood you, I need to put in the constructor of the rectangle PictureBox.PointToScreen(northEast.X) etc.?

Comment: I'd avoid having too many calls nested in the constructor (makes things difficult), but yes, something like that. Transform the two points into `TopLeft.X/Y` and `BottomRight.X/Y`. Note that the `PointToScreen` takes a `Point`, not just a single x or y value.

Comment: I'm going to try this (right now not working but we'll see) but to make clear - I was wrong and I should use PointToClient and not PointToScreen, right?

Answer (score 0):

Since your cropped Bitmap image size is the same as the width/height of the user selection, I'm guessing you want that cropped image to be in the top/left of the new Bitmap and fill it.  As it is, you're telling the DrawImage() method to draw that portion of the Bitmap in the same location, albeit in a smaller size Bitmap.

The correct way to do this is to draw the source rectangle image at (0, 0):

```
    private Point pt1, pt2;

    private void AP_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // ... obviously other code here ...            

        else if (mark_shape == 0) // Setting the corners
        {
            Point pt = AP.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
            if (picture_corners_set == 0)
            {
                pt1 = new Point(pt.X, pt.Y);
                picture_corners_set = 1;
            }
            else if (picture_corners_set == 1)
            {
                pt2 = new Point(pt.X, pt.Y);
                picture_corners_set = 0;

                Rectangle imageRectangle = new Rectangle(new Point(Math.Min(pt1.X, pt2.X), Math.Min(pt1.Y, pt2.Y)), new Size(Math.Abs(pt2.X - pt1.X) + 1, Math.Abs(pt2.Y - pt1.Y) + 1));
                var bmp = new Bitmap(imageRectangle.Width, imageRectangle.Height);
                using (var gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
                {
                    gr.DrawImage(AP.Image, 0, 0, imageRectangle, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                }
                AP.Image = bmp;
                enableAllButtons();
            }
        }
    }
```

There are several other overloads you could use to do this, but the one above makes it pretty clear that `imageRectangle` is being drawn at (0, 0).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have converted the coordinates using PointToClient but it still takes a small part of the image and stretches it. I've noticed that the image width and height are actually bigger than my screen resolution - could it be a problem? My computer is 1366*768, height is 1280 and width 1832...

Comment: Update your original post with the code of the **Events** you're using to set the points.